# All of my API calls were working on Friday and are now broken

Tags: api

What just happened at Salesforce? As of Friday my code was working. My code would assemble URLs such as this:

```
https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v35.0/sobjects
```

This is the instance url I get when my code first logins with my credentials:

```
https://na15.salesforce.com/
```

The rest of the URL was working fine.

Today I get a 404 error on everything.

Are there new URLs that I should target? If yes, where do I get the new list of URLs?

And again, this worked fine on Friday morning:

```
https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v34/sobjects/Opportunity
```

but now I get:

```
  {:orig-content-encoding nil,
              :trace-redirects
                         ["https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v34/sobjects/Opportunity"],
              :request-time 427,
              :status 404,
              :headers
              {"Connection" "close",
               "Transfer-Encoding" "chunked",
               "Content-Type" "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
               "Expires" "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT",
               "Set-Cookie"
               "BrowserId=rx70FYsvQpGI8onupo9MTw;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Wed, 25-Nov-2015 20:28:54 GMT",
               "Date" "Sat, 26 Sep 2015 20:28:54 GMT"},
              :body
              "[{\"errorCode\":\"NOT_FOUND\",\"message\":\"The requested resource does not exist\"}]"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just checked with workbench and the exact URL is

```
https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Opportunity
```

> Observe that there is .0 after version

You can experiment all REST calls using workbench

https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php

Documentation for REST is as below

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_rest.pdf